# Parameter missing, checked spelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new rails app, with a CRUD action for `links`
Here's some code.

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @link = Link.new
    end

    def create
        @link = Link.new(link_params)
        @link.save
        redirect_to @link
    end

    private

    def link_params
        params.require(:title).permit(:title, :name, :description, :link)
    end

end
```

And in my form I have an entry for `:title` which I am filling in. But I am still getting the error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in LinksController#create, param is missing or the value is empty: title

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your params in rails server console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in LinksController#create, param is
>   missing or the value is empty: title

According to your code, the `link_params` method should be

```
def link_params
  params.require(:link).permit(:title, :name, :description, :link)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this..

```
params.require(:link).permit(:title, :name, :description, :link)
```

Hope this will work for you